# visual studio 2015 ctp 6 can not start up on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

i want to try vs2015 on my windows 10 technical preview.9926.
but it can not start up.i check the system event logs. it say'

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__4(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

i think i will be cause by the dotNet framework version. so i update it from 4.5.0 to 4.5.1,and i try to install 4.6.but it not working .and i try to remove all the dotnet framework and try to reinstall it, also not working. why, what can i do ?

and i use the dotNet framework 4.6 preview from msdn, but the remove wizard show my installed version is 4.5.3. what happend here.

Comment: Same issue here :( on Windows 8.1. Did yoy find a solution?

Comment: i dont know why , but it look like cause by the framework, i use tool clean all dotnet framework, and reinstall vs2015, and it working.